# Populando DIV após selecionar um dado na lista

Tags: php, jquery, json

Alguém poderia me ajudar com esse codigo? Assumo que nao entendo cerca de 80%, estou tentando popular a div INFO apos selecionar uma das opções no campo SELECT, essas informações serão relativas a opção selecionada, as informações relativas a opção selecionada está contida na pagina exemplo.php... Do jeito que está, está funcionando, porem as informações estão sendo apresentadas dentro de um OPTION, eu gostaria ao menos que fosse populados dentro de um INPUT

```
<html>
 <head>
<title>Exemplo</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<label for="montadora">Montadora:</label>
<select name="montadora" id="montadora">
<option value="1">Fiat</option>
<option value="2">Ford</option>
<option value="3">Volkswagen</option>
</select>
<br />
<label for="veiculo">Veiculo:</label>
<select name="veiculo" id="veiculo"></select>    

<div id="INFO">      
</div>      

<script type="text/javascript">      
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#montadora").change(function(){
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "exemplo.php",
data: {montadora: $("#montadora").val()},
dataType: "json",
success: function(json){
var options = "";
$.each(json, function(name, value){
options += '<option value="' + name + '">' + name + '</option>';
});
$("#veiculo").html(options);
}
});
});
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perceba a linha

```
options += '<option value="' + name + '">' + name + '</option>';
```

ela é responsável por criar os valores dentro da tag option, para alterar basta alterar a linha para a tag desejada. No caso de `input` do tipo `texto` ficaria algo como.

```
options += '<input type="text" value="' + name + '"/>';
```

Para remover o `input` e apresentar o texto de forma limpa basta remover as tags e deixar somente a variável `name`.

Verifique também que os dados são incluidos dentro do `select` com id `veiculos`. Para alterar para a div com id `info` você deve alterar a linha

```
$("#veiculo").html(options);
```

Para

```
$("#info").html(options);
```

Comment: Você saberia me dizer como posso eliminar o JSON e usar uma consulta normal?? Nao sei usar JSON

Comment: Se com consulta normal você se refere a carregar HTML, você pode utilizar o [jQuery Load](http://api.jquery.com/load/). Bastando informar onde será colocado o conteúdo carregado. Algo como: 
`$( "#INFO" ).load( "pagina.html" );`